# Where are the Overdue Books?

Tags: fallout-4

In the Boston Public Library you can get reward tokens for turning in books that are overdue. Where are they located? I've only been able to find 3 and I've searched for an hour. Are some not located in the library?

Comment: Be aware that even though there are several machines where you can return overdue books for the tokens, the 'prizes' on offer at each machine differs and one machine in particular has a unique item for 50 tokens that I doubt anyone will want to pass up.

Comment: @DngnRdr Care to elaborate or provide a reference pointer for that 50 token item? So far I've seen nothing but worthless junk.

Comment: @Iszi There is a machine in the Boston Public Library that has a Massachusetts Surgical Journal, which is the most notable loot from any of these book return terminals. For a full list of rewards and where to claim them, check out the [Fallout Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Overdue_book#Book_return_terminal_prize_list) page.

Comment: @king14nyr Most compelling item yet, I think. Pretty sure I've seen some other lists that had a couple interesting/rare weapons or ammo, but nothing too spectacular. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are definitely some outside of the library. I've collected a list from a couple of sources... Namely, [GamesWiki](http://gameswiki.net/fallout-4-robot-model-kit-and-overdue-books-location-guide/) and [Fallout Wikia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Overdue_book). The schools scattered throughout the game seem to be a great place to pick up a number of these in one location. You can check these articles for a bit more description on precise location, but combining the lists in their current state yields:

- 9 in East Boston Preparatory School
- 8 in Shaw High School
- 6 inside the Boston Public library
- 5 in Suffolk County Charter School
- 4 in Trinity Church
- 4 in D.B. Technical High School
- 4 in Collegiate Administration Building
- 4 in Sandy Coves Convalescence Home
- 3 in a Pulowski Preservation Shelter, South end of Trinity Plaza
- 3 in Natick Police Department
- 2 in subway station West of Hangman's Alley
- 2 in the Kendall Hospital
- 2 in the ArcJet Systems building
- 1 in the laundromat in Lexington
- 1 in the Walden Pond gift shop
- 1 in USAF Satellite Station Olivia
- 1 in Faneuil Hall
- 1 in a trader's shack west of Ranger cabin
- 1 in Quincy Police Department
- 1 in Mass Fusion building
- 1 as quest reward for Public Knowledge, given by Daisy in Goodneighbor
- 1 in Covenant
- 1 in the subway tunnels during the quest The Big Dig
- 1 in Saugus Ironworks
- 1 in Harbormaster Hotel
- 1 in Lexington Apartments
- 1 in Boston Mayoral Shelter
- 1 in Pulowski Preservation Shelter in front of D.B. Technical High School
- 1 in Bethany's Shack, NW of ArcJet Systems
- 1 in Parkview Apartments
- 1 in Milton General Hospital
- 1 in Parsons State Insane Asylum
- 1 in Museum of Witchcraft
- 1 in Plumber's Secret, Cambridge

Overdue books may also be for sale at some vendors, including general stores in settlements.

Book return tokens can also occasionally be looted. Most notably, the raiders around Revere Beach Station and the loot containers of that area can contain book return tokens, presumably obtained by the raiders from the book return terminal in the nearby building.

Comment: This list is certainly incomplete as I don't see a single BATFL station on it. I know I've found Overdue Books (and return stations) at a couple of those while going through Nick Valentine's companion quest.

Comment: @Iszi Yeah, I provided the two source links that I used to originally put this list together because those are probably the best sources to get a more comprehensive list. I'd have to edit my answer constantly if I tried to keep up with all the changes and updates there. For the scope of this answer, I wanted to show there were indeed overdue books not in the library, and give the asker at least a few alternate locations.