# Where should I return all of my overdue library books?

Tags: fallout-4

I've found [Overdue Books all over the wasteland.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243160/where-are-the-overdue-books) It's not particularly surprising that a little thing like Nuclear War would keep people from returning things to their friendly local library, I guess. Fortunately, the Boston Public Library has an innovative and automated system to pay a bounty for the return of overdue books! It's mostly stuff like childrens toys, but I noticed one of the terminals at the Library itself had a copy of the Massachusets Journal of Surgery availiable. Sweet! Kids love anatomy!

So, anyways, it's clear that the various book-depositing-terminals offer different rewards at different prices. Where are all of the Overdue Library terminals, and which of them stock notable rewards, as opposed to standard wasteland junk, that I should be hoarding my Book Tokens to acquire?

Comment: I've found a handful of other terminals, but they all seem to be selling the same not-super-useful junk.  Not an answer as I don't have a detailed list of where I found them.

Comment: I found an overdue book terminal in http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/East_Boston_Preparatory_School you exchanged books for tokens, and then used `x` number of tokens to buy items.

Comment: @DavidYell yeah, there are several in police stations, schools and other similarly municipal-minded locations.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Ah cool, that's the only one I've found so far! Will keep hunting :)

Answer (score 21):

Looking at the wikia and the one I found, there are multiple locations for these terminals (http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Overdue_book).  The locations are:

- Boston Public Library
- Suffolk County Charter School
- East Boston Preparatory School
- Natick Police Department
- Kendall Hospital
- Quincy Police Station
- In a building next to the Revere Beach Station (not sure if the building has a name)
- Sandy Coves Convalescent home

For the rewards, here's a list of some of the better rewards (http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Book_return_token):

- Fusion Core (**50 tokens**): Building next to Revere Beach Station (1 available)
- Massachusetts Surgical Journal (**50 tokens**): Boston Public Library/SW Room (1 available)
- Stimpak (**10 tokens**): Building next to Revere Beach Station (5 available)
- Jet (**10 tokens**): Building next to Revere Beach Station (3 available)
- Fragmentation Grenade (**15 tokens**): Building next to Revere Beach Station (5 available)

The rest are not that great, but the Stimpak, Jet, and Frag grenade I listed in case anyone wants them.

If anyone knows or finds good rewards at any other terminals or locations, add a comment and I can edit my answer to include the additional locations/rewards.

Comment: ... Of course the machine in Revere would dispense drugs.

Comment: "Thanks for the books kids, have a live grenade!"

Comment: @Namfuak Also in Revere. Also unsurprising.

Comment: 10mm bullets and a Combat Knife are the other items dispensed Revere book return kiosk.  You'll think this is poking fun of a place where guns and violence seem to frequently make the news...

Answer (score 3):

The various Overdue Library Books that are littered throughout the Commonwealth can be returned to any of the following locations;

- Boston Public Library
- East Boston Preparatory School
- Kendall Hospital
- Natick Police Department
- Quincy Police Station
- Revere Beach Station
- Suffolk County Charter School

There are terminals present at each of these locations that you can interact with which allow you to return these books in exchange for tokens. [A full list of all of the items you can redeem the tokens in exchange for can be found here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Overdue_book).