# Is there a use for burnt books or magazines?

Tags: fallout-4

My Misc Inventory is starting to get a little unwieldy, finding Holotapes I've recently picked up by name is hard enough even when they're not surrounded by Burnt Magazines, Other Holotapes, Bobbleheads, [Overdue Books](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/244832/28182) and Subway Tokens etc.*

I know I can drop them or leave them in a container in a settlement (and indeed, have resorted to doing so), but I'm wondering whether I need to pick them up at all. I definitely don't want to come across the [Burnt Magazine Dungeon](http://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2011/11/14/thulsa-broom) and wonder why I didn't collect all these 'useless' items, but at the same time I'm getting sick of searching through them to find the current Misc item I need.

The Wikis <sup>[1](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Burnt_lifestyle_magazine), [2](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Burnt_fashion_magazine), [3](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Burnt_trade_magazine), [4](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Burnt_comic)...</sup> of the items don't go into great detail, So, do any of the 'burnt' items (Books, Magazines etc) have a use?

<sub>* Holotapes should have an entire section to themselves IMO</sub>

Comment: +1 for the Penny Arcade reference.  That comic is totally me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like they cannot be used for anything as of now. Some people speculate that it can become useful in some mods.

They take up space in return for some resources:

[Vendor Trash](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3see4f/use_for_misc_stuff/): "Burnt stuff is just vendor trash"

[Just for deco, possibly for mods](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps4/164592-fallout-4/answers/413770-burnt-books-and-magazines): "According to Survival guide, it's for deco at the moment."

[Point 6: "Free caps or free resources"](http://www.gamerevolution.com/features/wasteland-survival-guide-10-tips-for-fallout-4-before-you-start): "On that note, anything that doesn't have any weight should be picked up immediately, like pencils, pre-war money, and even burnt magazines. All of these are either free caps or just free resources."

[Steam community](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/496881136904528854/) : "You can trade them, but you'll only get something like a single bottlecap each."

All of these links (apart from the second) state that the burnt items are not of any use. The second one states that it's just deco and that they might somehow be used by mods in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The overdue books can be returned for tokens. The Tokens can be used to buy stimpaks and other goodies at one particular place near the northagen settlement (or whatever it's called). The rest are just for show. Books are worthless but the burnt mags can be sold for one bottlecap each.

Comment: Hi, you're right with the overdue books. Although, the books can be brought back at any Book return machine (big red machines with terminals on the front). The most obvious location is the Boston library. Please also consider my edit for your grammar/writing style.